# Pre-populate recipients list on Docusign for Salesforce Lightning

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-lightning

I know this feature is available for the old Salesforce UI, but couldn't find anywhere how to pre-populate recipients using Docusign Lightning component.

Has anybody been able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

With SalesForce "classic" you could use a JavaScript button to prepopulate recipient info when the DocuSign Envelope is created. However, it appears that SalesForce Lightening [does not support](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/why-its-time-to-break-up-with-javascript-buttons-and-embrace-lightning.html) JavaScript buttons.

To customize "Send with DocuSign" behavior in SalesForce Lightening, you might try the following approach:

1. Create a Visualforce page that launches an APEX class controller that opens a URL.
2. Create a class to define that controller.
3. Create a new action on the opportunity and associate the Visualforce page to the action.
4. Add the Action to the appropriate area on the Opportunity page layout.

You can find a code sample for this type of implementation on this thread in the SalesForce Developer forum:  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BWr4IAG. And, this other SO post shows an attempt to implement this approach to customize the *Send with Docusign* behavior: [Customize "Send With Docusign" in Salesforce Lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317136/customize-send-with-docusign-in-salesforce-lightning).

***Note:*** I'm not a SalesForce developer and this answer is simply recommending an approach that others seem to have used in the scenario you've described.

Comment: thanks Kim! so far, the only workaround I was able to use was creating a lightning component that fires an `urlEvent`.